# modprobe: Command not Found

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I want to install Virtualbox on my Ubuntu 14.04,but when I want to start any VM it say that no kernel Modules found.

So I want to install it with `/sbin/vboxconfig`

but it say that

```
modprobe vboxdrv failed please use dmesg to find why
```

So I tried to enter modprobe but then it say me command not Found?
Is there any Module that is not installed?
I have another Ubuntu PC there is no Problem to run this Command,
In my Case its a Hardware Server and I want to install Virtualbox.

Thank you

Comment: Have you used dmesg to find why?

Comment: Yes but there is so Mutch and i cant understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command not found` is the standard error message you receive when you enter a command that requires privileges you don't have -- in this case, it must be entered with root privilege.  If you type `sudo` before your command line, you'll be requesting that privilege, and will be prompted for your user password.  Then, assuming your user account is in the `sudoers` group, the command will be executed with root privilege.

Comment: I am logged in always as a root User. So i dont need the sudo commend.

Answer (score 0):

The path of modprobe is `/sbin/modprobe`.

Zeiss Ikon's answer assumes you are trying to run modprobe as a non-root user therefore not finding modprobe because `/sbin` is usually not contained in the `PATH` variable of a non-root user.

If you are a root user the `PATH` variable usually contains `/sbin` so that you can run `modprobe`.

However, if you switched to a root user with `su` (depending on the implementation) it may happen that the `PATH` variable is not updated.
In that case use `su -` instead of `su` (or use the full path but "using `su -` is strongly recommended").
See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/460769/231334).